# Uppercase condition for polymer template

Tags: javascript, polymer, uppercase

How to apply `upperCase` condition in template if in polymer. My code is:

```
if="[[ifIsOfType(abc.status,'final'.toUpperCase())]].
```

I applied this but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Polymer cannot parse complex expressions in the HTML attributes since 1.0. So you have to move your conversion to the function you are calling.